# Invoking function present in a higher module

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, test-bench

My SystemVerilog (non-UVM) code has the below structure:

`tb` instantiates wrapper which instantiates another module `A`.

From a function inside module `A`, how I can call a function inside `tb`?

I tried invoking tb.function; however during simulation stage, we run into the below error:

> NULL pointer dereference, Verilog stack trace for tb_top.function

Comment: *null pointer referece error* means that you did not **new** the wrapper before its use.  Please provide a reproducer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly call the function declared in the higher module from the lower module, without using a hierarchical path.  Or, you can use the top module name.  Both of these calls work:

```
module A;
    function void afunc;
        $display("Hello from %m");
        tbfunc();
        tb.tbfunc();
    endfunction
    initial afunc();
endmodule

module tb;
    function void tbfunc;
        $display("Hello from %m");
    endfunction

    A A ();
endmodule
```

Prints:

```
Hello from tb.A.afunc
Hello from tb.tbfunc
Hello from tb.tbfunc
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 23.8 *Upwards name referencing*:

> A lower level module can reference items in a module above it in the
> hierarchy. ... For tasks, functions, named blocks, and generate
> blocks, SystemVerilog shall look in the enclosing module for the name
> until it is found or until the root of the hierarchy is reached.

Note: from your error message (`tb_top.function`), it looks like you are using the `function` keyword instead of the **name** that you gave to the function.  That is not allowed.